# What is Scala's Simple Build Tool (sbt) and why is it used?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new in Scala and I have to learn Scala and SBT, I read the sbt tutorial but i am unable to understand the use of sbt, for what purpose its been used.After reading this [tutorial](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html) 
I am still confused can any one will explain it in simple words, also suggest me if there is some tutorial for simple build tool

Answer (score 96, accepted):

When you write small programs that consist of only one, or just two or three source files, then it's easy enough to compile those source files by typing `scalac MyProgram.scala` in the command line.

But when you start working on a bigger project with dozens or maybe even hundreds of source files, then it becomes too tedious to compile all those source files manually. You will then want to use a build tool to manage compiling all those source files.

sbt is such a tool. There are other tools too, some other well-known build tools that come from the Java world are [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

How it works is that you create a project file that describes what your project looks like; when you use sbt, this file will be called `build.sbt`. That file lists all the source files your project consists of, along with other information about your project. Sbt will read the file and then it knows what to do to compile the complete project.

Besides managing your project, some build tools, including sbt, can automatically manage dependencies for you. This means that if you need to use some libraries written by others, sbt can automatically download the right versions of those libraries and include them in your project for you.

Comment: If you'd like to learn more about how to use Scala Build Tool, SBT. Refer to this article. It has reference to other useful articles as well: http://www.codesynch.com/hadoop_spark_blog/sbt-scala-build-tool-unix-install-sbteclipse-plugin-sample-wordcount/

Comment: Build tools for java, C, etc are already on my system, so why does scala need another different build tool of its very own?  Can't scala use ant like every other buildable language?

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson because sbt build file can contain scala code?